# How to write this using recursion?

Tags: c++, recursion

I have a formula: `a*v^4 + b*v^3 + c*v^2 + d*v` which calculates fuel_per_hour of a car which has `t` liters fuel and is going `m` kilometers (`v` is average speed (kilometers per hour) and `a`, `b`, `c` and `d` are constants and are given to me as well as `m` and `t` )  I need to write a recursive function to calculate maximum amount of `v` to arrive to destination and `t` (amount of available fuel) must not get below zero with that speed.

So here's what i have tried. in two test cases it calculates the ans with 0.01 difference! in another test case result differs from true answer :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>
using namespace std;

double calculate_ambulance_max_speed( double, double, double, double, double, double, double );
void print_in_precision_two( double );

int main()
{
    double ambulance_max_speed;
    double a, b, c, d, m, t;
    //double a = 1.559e-7, b = 1.8195e-5, c = 0.0022233, d = 0.31292, m = 58.902, t = 85.585; // shows 142.66 , correct answer is 142.65!
    //double a = 2.8e-8, b = 7.6e-6, c = 0.0013, d = 0.47, m = 11.65, t = 20.81; // shows 257.52, correct ans is 257.45!
    //double a = 0.000001, b = 0.0001, c = 0.029, d = 0.2, m = 12, t = 100; // shows 134.42, correct ans is 134.41!
    double v = 100000;

    ambulance_max_speed = calculate_ambulance_max_speed( a, b, c, d, m, t, v );
    print_in_precision_two( ambulance_max_speed );
    cout << endl;

return 0;
}

void print_in_precision_two( double ambulance_max_speed )
{
    printf( "%.2f", ambulance_max_speed );  

}

double calculate_ambulance_max_speed( double a, double b, double c, double d, double m, double t, double v )
{
    double fuel_per_hour = a * pow( v, 4 ) + b * pow( v, 3 ) + c * pow( v, 2 ) + d * v;

    if( fabs( ( t - fuel_per_hour * m / v ) ) <= 0.01 )
        return v;
    else if( fabs( ( t - fuel_per_hour * m / v ) ) < 5 )
        return calculate_ambulance_max_speed( a, b, c, d, m, t, v - 0.01 );
    else if( fabs( ( t - fuel_per_hour * m / v ) ) < 10 )
        return calculate_ambulance_max_speed( a, b, c, d, m, t, v - 0.01 );
    else if( fabs( ( t - fuel_per_hour * m / v ) ) < 50 )
        return calculate_ambulance_max_speed( a, b, c, d, m, t, v - 5 );
    else if( fabs( ( t - fuel_per_hour * m / v ) ) < 100 )
        return calculate_ambulance_max_speed( a, b, c, d, m, t, v - 10 );
    else if( fabs( ( t - fuel_per_hour * m / v ) ) < 200 )
        return calculate_ambulance_max_speed( a, b, c, d, m, t, v - 50 );
    else if( fabs( ( t - fuel_per_hour * m / v ) ) < 300 )
        return calculate_ambulance_max_speed( a, b, c, d, m, t, v - 50 );
    else if( fabs( ( t - fuel_per_hour * m / v ) ) < 400 )
        return calculate_ambulance_max_speed( a, b, c, d, m, t, v - 50 );
    else if( fabs( ( t - fuel_per_hour * m / v ) ) < 500 )
        return calculate_ambulance_max_speed( a, b, c, d, m, t, v - 50 );
    else if( fabs( ( t - fuel_per_hour * m / v ) ) < 1000 )
        return calculate_ambulance_max_speed( a, b, c, d, m, t, v - 50 );
    else if( fabs( ( t - fuel_per_hour * m / v ) ) < 100000 )
        return calculate_ambulance_max_speed( a, b, c, d, m, t, v - 100 );
    else if( fabs( ( t - fuel_per_hour * m / v ) ) < 100000000000 )
        return calculate_ambulance_max_speed( a, b, c, d, m, t, v - 500 );
}
```

How can I fix the 0.01 differences? and why is second test case so much different to true answer?

Comment: I don't know how to implement the recursion part... should i start on a very high speed and place it in formula and call the function with slower speed in each recursive call to finally arrive to max speed? Isn't it too slow?

Comment: Do you have an iterative solution that works? Start with including that in your question.

Comment: I don't quite see why your problem calls for a recursive, or for that matter iterative, solution. It boils down to "solve the equation `a*v^3 + b*v^2 + c*v + d = t/m` for `v`". There's a closed form solution for cubic equations. What is there to loop or recurse over?